# variable not taking value in dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

Why is my `MESSAGE` variable not passed as value to dictionary?

Message variable which i want to pass as value in markdown:

```
MESSAGE= "CRITICAL eu1: app1.eu1 SD-IsAlive-eu1-ITSMAriesPrd ITSM Aries Production FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /mnt/nfs/isalive/WebServiceBridge.Out-201731816 is 66804 seconds old and 46 byts"
print (""+MESSAGE+"")
```

Dictionary with header and data:

```
headers = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer MTUxZDJmMmMtMWZjOC00YmU0LWFmMjMtMDhjZDRlYjc1ZmIzYzUxNTNlMWEtMjY2',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}
```

Adding message variable as value in data:

```
data ='{ "roomId": "Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNjk0ZjBhNjAtN2MxMy0xMWU3LTliZWYtODFiNDQxYjc0ZDhh", "markdown": MESSAGE}\n#'
```

Message variable added as value for markdown key:

```
print data
print MESSAGE
output----


CRITICAL eu1: app1.eu1 SD-IsAlive-eu1-ITSMAriesPrd ITSM Aries Production FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /mnt/nfs/isalive/WebServiceBridge.Out-201731816 is 66804 seconds old and 46 byts
{ "roomId": "Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNjk0ZjBhNjAtN2MxMy0xMWU3LTliZWYtODFiNDQxYjc0ZDhh", "markdown": MESSAGE}
```

MESSAGE not able to print the value

```
CRITICAL eu1: app1.eu1 SD-IsAlive-eu1-ITSMAriesPrd ITSM Aries Production FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /mnt/nfs/isalive/WebServiceBridge.Out-201731816 is 66804 seconds old and 46 byts
```

Comment: Please tag this python 3 or 2.7.  You have `print(x)` and then `print x`, so 2.7?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, both work in Python 2.7

Comment: its python 2.7 @C8H10N4O2

Comment: MESSAGE= "CRITICAL eu1: app1.eu1 SD-IsAlive-eu1-ITSMAriesPrd ITSM Aries Production FILE_AGE CRITICAL: /mnt/nfs/isalive/WebServiceBridge.Out-201731816 is 66804 seconds old and 46 byts"
 
 data ='{ "roomId": "Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNjk0ZjBhNjAtN2MxMy0xMWU3LTliZWYtODFiNDQxYjc0ZDhh", "markdown": MESSAGE}\n#'
 
 print data 
 
 { "roomId": "Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNjk0ZjBhNjAtN2MxMy0xMWU3LTliZWYtODFiNDQxYjc0ZDhh", "markdown": MESSAGE}
 
 variable MESSAGE value is not placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, `data = '{"markdown": MESSAGE}\n#'` is a **string**, and in no way the `MESSAGE` here is a variable, it's merely text.

If you want `data` to be a dictionary, remove the outer single quotes and everything after the last closing brace:

```
data = {"roomId": "some data", "markdown": MESSAGE}
```